# Dynamic GraphQL mutations in React with template literals

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gql, mutation

I am trying to send my Google OAuth response to gql mutation to authenticate the user/log them in. When getting the response from google, I am doing the following:

```
const authGQL = (user) => graphql(gql`
    mutation {
        LoginOrSignup(name: ${user.profileObj.name}, email: ${user.profileObj.email}, googleId: 
        ${user.googleId}, imageUrl: ${user.profileObj.imageUrl}) {
      name
      email
      googleId
      imageUrl
    }
  }
`);
```

This is within my mutations file:

```
const mutation = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Mutation',
    fields: {
        LoginOrSignup: {
            type: UserType,
            args: {
                name: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },
                email: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },
                googleId: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },
                imageUrl: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) }
            },
            resolve(parentValue, { name, email, googleId, imageUrl}, request) {
                return AuthService.verifyUser({ name, email, googleId, imageUrl, req: request })
            }
        }
    }
});
```

It's not reaching the resolve function and I am not sure why! Thanks in advance.

Comment: whats the error message?

Comment: Uncaught GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Expected ":", found Name "email".........

The mutation works just fine in graphiql - I can signup/login a user no problem.

Comment: oh i just noticed your'e using `gql` tag function. you can't pass variables dynamically like that through string interpolation using the tag function. you need to use graphql variables https://blog.logrocket.com/graphql-variables-in-simple-terms/ and pass them via `variables` key

Comment: thank you! I will look into that as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to azium for pointing me in right direction. I had to use variables:

```
const mutation = gql` 
mutation LoginOrSignup($name: String!, $email: String!, $googleId: String!, $imageUrl: String!, $id_token: String!){
  LoginOrSignup(name: $name, email: $email, googleId: $googleId, imageUrl: $imageUrl, id_token: $id_token) {
    email
    name
  }
}
`
```

Within React I had to set those variables by using props.mutate:

```
    props.mutate({
      variables: {
        name: res.profileObj.name,
        email: res.profileObj.email,
        googleId: res.googleId,
        imageUrl: res.profileObj.imageUrl,
        id_token: res.tokenObj.id_token
      }
    })
```